# Trouble resolving anko library version 0.9.1

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm trying to compile the anko-test project (https://github.com/yanex/anko-example.git) but gradle can't resolve the dependency to the library :

```
Error: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:0.9.1.
  Required by:
     anko-example:app:unspecified
```

here's my gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.5-2'
    repositories {
         jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.example.ankodemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:0.9.1'
}
```

I haven't change anything after cloning the project, any Idea what's going on?

Comment: https://github.com/yanex/anko-example/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: that's the project I cloned, and when I build it, I get the error message I post. I tried an earlier version with this `compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:0.9'` and it works. So I guess there's a problem with the `0.9.1` version

Comment: show `build.gradle`

Comment: @tufekoi thank you this is working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to be a [known issue](https://github.com/yanex/anko-example/issues/7) (that dependency hasn't been synced to jcenter yet).

Temporary solution is to add the anko bintray repository to your root `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/anko' }
    }
}
```